# What is the difference between IBM MobileFirst versions?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

What is the difference between IBM MobileFirst versions ? Is it a separate version ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking here.  Can you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: I am currently working on version 8 and I have no idea about the old version
What's new in this version?

Answer (score 1):

The MobileFirst Platform Foundation V8.0 [release notes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html) include a "What's New" section that describes the changes in 8.0.  This version has significant changes from previous versions.

The release notes for previous versions also include a "What's New" section that discusses the changes made in those versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you to check the blog here https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/whats-new/

and blogs under https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/ for detailed tutorials and migration cookbooks.